# How to close current JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have read similar topics but i did find answer there.

I created `JFrame` with close button. After click I want to close current window. I try `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`, or `setVisible(false)`.

```
public class Windows {
 JFrame frame;
 JFrame frame1;


public Windows(){

} 


 public JFrame getCreateFrame(){

  frame1 = new JFrame("Create User");
  frame1.setSize(500,500);
  frame1.setVisible(true);
  frame1.getContentPane().add(new Panels().getwelcomTxtLabelPanel1(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
  frame1.getContentPane().add(new Panels().getCreateUser(), BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
  frame1.getContentPane().add(new Panels().getUserLabel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
  frame1.getContentPane().add(new Panels().getUserField(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  return frame1;
     }
  }
```

Here is a button.

```
public JButton getCancelButton(){

 cancel = new JButton("cancel");
 cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          new Windows().getCreateFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

              }
         });
return cancel;
     }
```

Comment: And what's not happening as expected?

Comment: it's disappears just 0,01s hard to see it even. It's works when i press exit

Comment: The whole structure of your code is wrong. You need to start over. Start with the `ButtomDemo.java` code found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Remove two of the buttons and rename the other to "Exit" and then add your exit code to the ActionListener. The tutorial shows you how to better structure your code and use invokeLater() to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I'm guessing, you keep creating frames, rather then maintains a reference to the frame to which y want to work with

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following action (and not only this):

```
cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      new Windows().getCreateFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
   }
});
```

here you create a new `Windows` object and call `getCreateFrame()` which creates a new `JFrame` and then you call `setDefaultCloseOperation()` on it.

So **you work with different `Windows` / `JFrame` instances.**

Instead you should create your `JFrame` in the constructor of `Windows` and call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)` of this `JFrame` in the constructor as well.

Afterwards you can use `setVisible(false)` in your action - but for this `JFrame` and not for a new created one.

BTW. `getCancelButton()` should most probably not create a new button every time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the frame invisible and dispose it.

```
JFrame frame;

frame.setVisible(false);
frame.dispose();
```

This completely closes the frame. If only this frame is open and no nondeamon threads are running, the program will quit after disposing the frame.

Comment: it's not working with frame.setVisible(false); and 
frame.dispose();

Comment: `You have to make the frame invisible and dispose it.`  you don't need to make the frame invisible first. All you need to do is invoke dispose() on the frame.

Comment: you create a new window every time you call 'getCreateWindow()'. You have to close window that is already visible.

Comment: I left just frame.dispose(); and it doesn't work.

Comment: @krychuq, your code has a terrible structure. Delete it and start over. It is better to start with a working example and customize it than it is to try to modify poorly structured code.